# split a string after it finds a "," and an integer

Tags: python, regex, split

For example consider a string:

```
str1 = '1=apple, 2=orange, mango, 3=grape'
#split string by ,
chunks = str1.split(', ')
```

if i run the code it gives me an output:
'1=apple', '2=orange', 'mango', '3=grape'

but I want my output to be:
'1=apple', '2=orange, mango', '3=grape'

Comment: you should look at regex and `re.split` it allows you to split using regular expressions

Answer (score 3):

With the [regex module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) you can model this exactly with a positive lookahead. This says, split on a a comma and space that is followed by a number:

```
import re

str1 = '1=apple, 2=orange, mango, 3=grape'

re.split(r', (?=\d)', str1)
# ['1=apple', '2=orange, mango', '3=grape']
```

Comment: how does that work? (It works tho ive tried but,) If im not mistaken, `\d` is for digit, but youve put the `=` before the `\d`. I would imagine that means (for example) `, =3` instead of `, 3=`

Comment: @MuhdMairaj, `(?=` is regex syntax for a lookead (it's just a coincidence that there's also an equals sign in your string). It mean "followed by". So `(?=\d)` means followed by a digit. The the whole regex reads, "a comma and a space [ that is followed by] a digit". This prevents it from splitting on the second comma (that is not followed by a digit).

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks, understood it now. I hadnt worked with re module too much so i got confused about that